# MySQL insert sets date to 30.11.-0001 if empty

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a form where I can insert some data which is getting stored in the server.

The form contains many date fields. I noticed that if I left a date field empty, then it is set to **30.11.-0001**

How can I just store an empty string if the date field is empty?

The default value of the date fields is set to NULL in phpmyadmin.

**Insert Method:**

```
public function insert($data)
{
    if (empty($data)) {
        error_log(get_class() . " - " . __FUNCTION__ . " : data not set or empty");
        return false;
    }

    $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $sql = " INSERT INTO ". self::TABLE
            ." ( "
                . "  property_id"
                . ", country_id"
                . ", property_item_type_id"
                . ", prio"
                . ", reg_date"
                . ", reg_no"
                . ", files_no"
                . ", release_date"
                . ", entry_date"
                . ", status"
                . ", runtime_max"
                . ", runtime_payed"
                . ", prio_date"
                . ", info"
                . ", create_date"
                . ", create_by"
                . ", update_date"
                . ", update_by"
            . " ) "
        . " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    $stmt = $this->con->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param(
        "iiiissssssssssssss"
        // i
        ,$data["property_id"]
        ,$data["country_id"]
        ,$data["property_item_type_id"]
        ,$data["prio"]
        // s
        ,$data["reg_date"]
        ,$data["reg_no"]
        ,$data["files_no"]
        ,$data["release_date"]
        ,$data["entry_date"]
        ,$data["status"]
        ,$data["runtime_max"]
        ,$data["runtime_payed"]
        ,$data["prio_date"]
        ,$data["info"]
        ,$now
        ,$data["email"]
        ,$now
        ,$data["email"]
    );
    $stmt->execute();

    $message["error"] = "Unable to insert new item!";
    return $this->checkAffectedRows($stmt, $message);
}
```

Comment: well. set it as empty string

Comment: @YourCommonSense, How? If I try then I get `Invalid default value for 'fieldname'`

Comment: Correction. set it as null

Comment: @YourCommonSense, as you can read in my question, it is already set to NULL ...

Comment: Please show some code, when you set it as Null, no problem should arrise. It is a different case if you send an empty string.

Comment: You asked, "How can I just store an empty string if the date field is empty?" so the answer is "store it as null"

Comment: @YourCommonSense, I already tried that, makes no difference.

Comment: then it is some of your other software to blame. when you store a null value in a mysql database it is stored as null.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, You were right. The original programmer attempted to store it as a NULL string... I just noticed it now. I changed it to NULL and now it works :)

Comment: @YourCommonSense, do you want to answer the question so that I can accept it?

Comment: You can answer your own questions as well. Not to mention I don't know what is the current value. If it it's an empty string then instead of `,$data["reg_date"]` you can write `, $data["reg_date"] ?: null`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to check if the values are empty and set them to `NULL` before storing them to the database if they are.

```
$data["release_date"] = (strtotime($data["release_date"]) === false) ? NULL : $data["release_date"];
```